# Can JGroups be utilized to form the Java equivalent of COMET/Long-Polling?

Tags: java, swing, comet, long-polling, jgroups

In webdev-land, COMET/Lojg-Polling allows the server to maintain an open connection with each client and push data to each client as it becomes available. JGroups seems like it can be made to do the same thing between a client Swing application and its application server.

Is this a fair comparison or way off base?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main motive of JGroups API is for clustering, what you are trying to achieve is a sustained socket connection.

You can create a client server like architecture using JGroups based on their node ranks. But for this you need to be a but more clear with the requirements.